# svn: E155010: Commit failed file missing error

Tags: svn

I made a few changes and tried to commit them to my SVN repository.

But when I try to commit the changes this is the error that I get:

```
[Tim@JEC206429674ML:~/Desktop/projects] #svn --force add *
[Tim@JEC206429674ML:~/Desktop/projects] #svn commit -m "added TVE and a few other documents"
svn: E155010: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E155010: '/Users/Tim/Desktop/projects/~$Project_Tracker.xlsx' is scheduled for addition, but is missing
```

I tied googling for answers after playing around with it for a little while. But I could only find answers pertaining to the reverse situation. Where a file was added but produces this error.

Any help anyone can offer on how to solve this would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I think you are trying to commit a temp file. Please verify that the file $Project_Tracker.xlsx exist. You must have run the add command while your excel file was open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure, the file `~$Project_Tracker.xlsx` is a lock file that Excel creates while you are editing `Project_Tracker.xlsx`.  It should not be added to version control.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to commit a temponary file. Please verify that the file `$Project_Tracker.xlsx` exist. You must have run the add command while your excel file was open.

And tried to commit when you closed the excel file or some thing like that. Please verify.
That lock file should not be added to source control.